# 1 Gigasecond is also a Teramilisecond?

Tags: local-time

I'm reasoning about some time parsing thing in JavaScript which
uses millisecond-precision for Date objects and Unix System time does use seconds.

Putting problems with precision loss for conversion- can one say if

if 10^9 seconds is a Gigasecond, then 10^12 Miliseconds is a Gigasecond  a Teramilisecond?

Comment: This should be asked on Stackoverflow :)

Comment: Thought the question is better at home here

Comment: Well, if your question is just about units, a quick google search is the answer; if its about how JS handles such things, it should go to Stackoverflow. This question has nothing to do with mathematics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about mathematics. It should be migrated to Stackoverflow.

Comment: I dont agree with you- read my question and let JS out of it

Answer (score 2):

If $10^9$ seconds is a gigasecond, $10^{12}$ seconds is a *terasecond*, not a teramillisecond. A teramillisecond would be $10^{12} \cdot 10^{-3} = 10^9$ seconds as well, but only one [metric prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) can be used on the same word.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected my question to be more precise.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the metric prefix naming rule

Comment: @Glorfindel: I don't see how the answer can be a yes. As you say, teramilli can't be used. (Nor millitera :-) )

Comment: @YvesDaoust you're right. I read the new version of the question wrong.

Comment: Anyway, *teratick* is probably acceptable.